# OneToOneField does not exist on instances of the related object

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a one-to-one relationship between two models in different apps.  It is giving me the error "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist" when I try to assign a value to that attribute.  When a Table is created, no attribute is set for party.  When a SeatedUser is created I create the relationship.  It is telling me that SeatedUser has no table

```
#apps/restaurants/models.py
class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name = "tables")
    party = models.OneToOneField(SeatedUser, related_name = "table", null = True, default = None)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    objects = RestaurantManager()

#apps/users/models.py
class SeatedUser(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    member = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name = "seatUser", null = True)
    objects = DataManager()

#apps/restaurants/views.py
def assignTable(request, tableId):
    myTable = Table.objects.get(id = tableId)

    lineMembers = LineMember.objects.filter(restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id = request.session["restaurant"]))

    lineMember = findCorrectUser(lineMembers, myTable.size)
    if lineMember == None:
        messages.success(request, "No parties to assign to this table")
        return redirect("/restaurants/dashboard")

    seatedUser = SeatedUser(
        member = lineMember.member
    )
    seatedUser.save()
    seatedUser.restaurant.add(Restaurant.objects.get(line = lineMember))
    seatedUser.table.add(myTable)
    lineMember.delete()

    messages.success(request, f"{seatedUser.member.lastName} assigned to table {table.name}")
    return redirect("/restaurants/dashboard")
```

I need to assign a Table to a SeatedUser, therefore assigning a SeatedUser to that Table.  I cannot figure out why it is telling me that this variable doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to create the Table instance - you don't get one automatically when you create a SeatedUser. I also think your design might not be correct... can a Table have more than one SeatedUser?

Comment: Table is already created.  Sorry, I should have added that code with it.  And no, a table cannot have more than one SeatedUser.  The naming isn't great, but a SeatedUser is actually a party, or group of people.

Comment: In that case you want `table.party = seatedUser`

Comment: This doesn't work.  The code is running now, and I don't get an error.  However, no association is made.  When I use the shell to look up myTable.party, there is nothing there.

Comment: Are you saving the `table` instance after setting the `party` property? It's tough to help when you don't update the code.

Comment: Ya, forgot to save.  That worked great.  Thanks a lot for the help.  Don't really understand why my method didn't work, guess I need to do some more reading about it.